<< De voyage en livre et de livre en voyage >> : la formulation <<de ... en>> ?
This is the title of a 'chronologie de Graham Greene' that forms part of the introductory material to a French-language edition of some of his short stories:

'De voyage en livre et de livre en voyage'

Is this an example of the << de ... en >> locution I know from phrases like << de temps en temps >> i.e. 'from ... to'? I am not used to seeing different nouns instead of the same one repeated.

I think it just means "from voyage to book and from book to voyage", not any special "de ... en ...:.

Nothing idiomatic.

Side note but if you don't have easy access to «  », it's much better to use " " than << >>.
